# check the datetimeindex element

Tags: python

Check if the elements of 'dates_to_be_searched' are present in DateTimeIndex, 'dates',

Note: Use the isin method associated with DatetimeIndex objects.

I wrote code like below

```
print(dates.isin(dates_to_be_searched['Date']))
```

The above code I am giving the output : `[False False False False False False False False  True False False False False  True False]`

But I cannot move to the next step, please suggest where is my mistake?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where are you stuck? Please check [ask] and add [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You may check for any element is present:

```
print(any(dates.isin(dates_to_be_searched['Date'])))
```

Or check for all of elements are present:

```
print(all(dates.isin(dates_to_be_searched['Date'])))
```

Comment: I have followed your answer and I got the output but still, I cannot move to the next step.

Comment: @MRINMOYEEBHATTACHARYA What do you mean exactly by "the next step"?

Comment: I'm trying to run this code base in Katacoda, after these steps it should move to the next steps as per the consequence. But somehow it's not moving to the next step. As per my assumption, katacoda is expecting some specific thing

Answer (score 0):

```
print(pd.DatetimeIndex.isin(dates_to_be_searched, dates))
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you need to switch the place of the variable.

print(dates_to_be_searched.isin(dates))